# How to dynamically determine mongo write concern

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to connect to a mongo database:

```
var options = {
    db: {
        w: 2, /* replica acknowledged */
        readPreference: 'nearest'
    }
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/some_db', options);
```

In my dev environment this mongodb will not be replicated which causes errors to occur when the write concern is set to 2:

```
cannot use 'w' > 1 when a host is not replicated
```

However in production it will be replicated so I need this setting. I figure I need a way to determine if the mongo I connected to is replicated and then if it is, set the write concern to 2 (like above).

One  solution to this that I could use is the node drivers [replSetGetStatus](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/admin.html#replsetgetstatus) and then check if the error returned indicates that mongo is not replicated.

This feels really dirty though, is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be setting a variable in your process.env depending on whether your app is running in development mode or production mode, then set write concern to 2 if it equals to 'production', else default to 1.

```
var options = {
    db: {
        w: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 2 || 1,
        readPreference: 'nearest'
    }
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/some_db', options);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason for using && instead of the ternary operator?

Comment: Personal preference mostly, nothing wrong with using ternary in this case.